# Error on OUT parameters on Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm getting the following error when executing my SP:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL   
server version for the right syntax to use near '; select @nodata_issue,@dateof_issue' 
at line 1
```

and

```
SQL Error (1414): OUT or INOUT argument 2 for routine proc1 is 
not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger
```

These parameters are declared like this:

```
PROCEDURE proc1(IN `idpap` INT, OUT `nodata_issue` TINYINT, OUT `dateof_issue` DATE)
```

*EDIT: Chunk of code that was changed and started the issue:

```
PROCEDURE proc1(IN `idpapel` INT, OUT `nodata_issue` TINYINT, OUT `dateof_issue` DATE)
  DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE primeira_mov, data_anterior DATE;
select data into primeira_mov from excel.trade_mov where papel = idpapel order by data LIMIT 1;

BLOCK1: begin

DECLARE ...
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR select data, valor_split, valor_div from excel.trade_correcao where data >= primeira_mov and id_papel = idpapel order by data DESC;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1329 BEGIN
        SET nodata_issue = 1;
        SET dateof_issue = datasplit;
    END;

set data_anterior = "2200-01-01";
set valor_aplicavel = 1;
set preco_fator = 1;
SET nodata_issue = 0;
SET dateof_issue = null;

CALL create_temp_tables();
TRUNCATE TABLE tbl1;


-- START TRANSACTION;

OPEN cur1;

read_loop_1: LOOP
```

Any ideas on what is causing this error?

Comment: I can see an `;` before your select. What is it doing there?

Comment: @eisberg Well this must be from the software I'm using to run the code (dbForge studio). I edited the post and included a proper SQL error

Comment: No it is MySQL generated and tells you where your error is.

Comment: @eisberg No, I don't have this line of code on my proc :)

Comment: MySQL cannot imagine code! Somewhere in your database is `; select @nodata_issue,@dateof_issue` and it is causing your problem if you believe it or not.

Comment: @ftkg The syntax error is from your procedure body. Why don't you post the procedure body? It would be easier to analyse it.

Comment: @Ravinder the proc is quite big, but I added the changes that started this issue.

Comment: @ftkg You may also require to post the before trigger body and explain what `create_temp_tables` procedure is about.

Comment: @ftkg This is still not the code with the `; select @nodata_issue,@dateof_issue` in it.

Comment: I don't have any triggers , nor this line of code..  this SP ran fine, until I added the out parameters, set the out parameters and the HANDLER FOR 1329.

Comment: `crate_temp_tables` only creates auxiliary temp tables.

Comment: @ftkg The syntax `select @nodata_issue,@dateof_issue` clarifies that the out variables `nodata_issue` and `dateof_issue` of SP are not called properly. Look for an example [***here***](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,505961,506002#msg-506002).

Comment: @Ravinder That's weird, I was calling it directly from 2 different programs. But look at this: I just called it from my java client and it works WITHOUT the `continue handler for 1329`. Do you know if I can have 2 handlers and they both trigger at the same time?

Comment: @ftkg May be. Meaning of the error may also be that *you passed in constant(s) instead of variable(s). OUT and INOUT parameters need something to store into.*. Best explanation is [*here in this thread*](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,162564,162756#msg-162756).